# Read txt file and insert values into database using PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a text file that contains values with line breaks, like this

```
Lawrence
Barse
Sifron
etc
etc
```

I want to read this file and insert each value into a Database Table.
I want the Front End Page to display information on each value that's inserted, like

```
Value Lawrence inserted successfully
```

So, I've written my PHP code like this

```
$count = 0;
$fileName = "names.txt";
    $fhandler = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fhandler, filesize($fileName));
    fclose($fhandler);

    $myArray = explode("\n", $theData);
```

So the variable $myArray contains all the values from the text file,

next I've written a Javascript function to send value from $myArray[0], to my data insertion php script page, which is something like this

```
<script >
    var cnt;
    function init()
    {
        var str = "<?php echo $myArray[$count] ?>";
        alert("Str is "+str);
    }
    function writeData(data)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("my_content").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
                    repeat();
                }
              }
            $data = ""+data+"";
            xmlhttp.open("GET","returnVals.php?b="+$data,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    function repeat()
    {
        <?php echo $count++; ?>
        cnt = "<?php echo $count ?>";
        var val = "<?php echo $myArray[$count] ?>";
        alert("Count is "+cnt+" and Val is "+val);
        writeData(val);
    }
</script>
```

My returnVals.php is the script that handle all the data insertion and echo's and output, that I print in the response handler.

Also, I know that I'm echoing php values inside javascript, which is not the standard way of programming, but I just don't see any other alternative. My Javascript repeat() function 
re calls the writeData function based on the $count value, but I'm not able to increment this value.

Is there a better way to achieve this...

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You are mixing client-side code with server-side code. The PHP blocks you are embedding in the JS code will execute **ONCE** when the page is generated, and then the PHP code is GONE. You need to learn about execution contexts and the differences between server-side and client-side.

Comment: Once you load the page in your browser, look at the source code. All those PHP calls will be gone. That is done on the server BEFORE it is send to your web browser. You cannot embed PHP in JavaScript. You cannot embed JavaScript in PHP. One runs on the server. The other runs on the client. If you need them to talk to one another, you need to use Ajax - which is VERY complicated for someone who is apparently learning to develop web applications.

Comment: So how do I traverse through the array to sequentially insert values from the array into the databse

Comment: What I don't understand is, since this file is ON the server why don't you insert this file into the database after reading and splitting it, then show the result in the HTML output! Why do you have to output this file to the browser then afterwards insert it into the database using AJAX request! I don't see the point to this, should not you be doing all this on the server and then output the result of the whole thing to the browser?

Comment: @ AL-Kateb, well the txt file is not on the server. The user needs to browse the file on his system and then the import takes place. Yes, I could just insert the values from the file into the database, but I want to show it happening sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I've run across a few times.  I've developed a non-AJAX pattern for long running import processes which exceed PHP timeouts before they complete.  One day I might upgrade it to AJAX but this seems pretty straightforward to me.  Hopefully it is of some help to you.

### PATTERN

- jump to the new starting point
- output fixed number of new records
- write out continue link
- auto reload (optional) to the continue link

### CODE

```
<?php
// variables
$num_rows = 25;  // number of rows to handle per page view

// get the starting index
$start_at  = (isset($_REQUEST['start'])) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0;
$new_start = $start_at + $num_rows;

// skip ahead to $start_at
$in_file   = fopen(...);
for ($i = 0; $i < $start_at; $i++) {
    // skip over this many rows
    fgets($in_file);
}

// process num_rows
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    $line = fgets($in_file);

    // process the line

    $morework = !!$line;  // fgets returns FALSE when done
}

// write out continue link with auto reload trigger
if ($morework) {
    echo "<a id='clickme' href='/my/page?start={$new_start}'>Continue from {$new_start}</a";
    echo "<script>";
        echo "window.location = document.getElementById('clickme').href";
    echo "</script>";
} else {
    echo "DONE";
}
```